# Calculating an average rate based on multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to calculate an average fare rate per square metre. To do this, I want to calculate the total cost by multiplying the *Quantity* (col `E`), the *Footprint* (col `Q`) and the netcon objective per square metre (col `AI`) to get the total cost per line item, adding all these up, then dividing by the total footprint (`E*Q`) for the whole list (lines 4 to 503, most of which are generally blank).

Since I want to avoid any more helper columns, I'm hoping to find a one-cell solution. To that end, I tried building an array formula:

```
=($E$4:$E$503*$Q$4:$Q$503*$AI$4:$AI$503)/SUM($E$4:$E$503*$Q$4:$Q$503)
```

It gives a `#VALUE!` error, though, and since it's my first attempt at actually writing an array formula rather than just copy-pasting one I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: And you've committed it correctly using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER?

Comment: Yup. I've just tried without the $, in case that was the problem, but it doesn't make any difference. I've also made sure that all the cells referenced are in fact numbers (as it claims col E is the wrong data type).

Comment: When enter an array formula, when you are done editing, instead of pressing enter, press CTRL+SHFT+ENTER at the same time.  You will see Excel place { } around your formula.  you cannot do it manually.

Comment: Yes, I've done that. I take it, then, that the formula itself looks all right?

Comment: seems to so far.  Try breaking it down into parts.  and limiting it to say 1 line then two lines.  If you can get it to work on two lines, then there is not reason it should not work on your full range

Comment: Just tried `=SUM(E4:E503*Q4:Q503)` to see if that worked, and I'm still getting the same error. Could it get confused by blank cells or formulae?

Comment: You say that you've correctly committed it as an array formula. Can you confirm then that the curly brackets {} appear around your formula in the formula bar?

Comment: They do appear, yes.

Comment: I was just checking about blank lines and the array formula you wrote works with or without it being entered as an array.  not as in giving the same answer, but as in not generating an error

Comment: What do you mean by "as it claims col E is the wrong data type"?

Comment: @ForwardEd Though if those "blanks" were in fact null strings, i.e. "", then a #VALUE! error would indeed be the result. However, the OP has confirmed that all entries in that column are numbers.

Comment: I get a #VALUE! error, the mouseover says one of the source cells is of the wrong data type, and when I go to Evaluate Formula it highlights the E and Q references as "The next evaluation will result in an error".

Comment: XOR, they're calculated numbers; I'll doublecheck, as I suspect they may indeed be null rather than blank.

Comment: ?? You said they were all numbers! How is a blank cell a number??

Comment: The values in column Q are indeed `""` rather than true blanks, but the cells in col E are either numbers or properly empty.

Comment: XOR, because I was looking at column E and forgetting the null strings in col Q. It's early morning and I've only had one coffee yet. ;-)

Comment: So try something like: =SUM(E4:E503*N(+Q4:Q503))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are interested in avoiding an array formula this looks like a sumproduct operation.  You could try this:

```
=sumproduct($E$4:$E$503,$Q$4:$Q$503,$AI$4:$AI$503)/sumproduct($E$4:$E$503,$Q$4:$Q$503)
```

and for your original formula, were you missing SUM at the start?

```
=sum($E$4:$E$503*$Q$4:$Q$503*$AI$4:$AI$503)/SUM($E$4:$E$503*$Q$4:$Q$503)
```

Comment: I just want to avoid adding more columns; I'm quite happy with using arrays, if I can figure out how to make them work. But if sumproduct works and my arrays don't, then I'll go with it. I'll give it a try and report back, thanks!

Comment: the above is a single cell answer

Comment: Yup, that's why I'm trying it. And it seems to work nicely. Cheers!

Comment: Andrew, I updated my answer, may have found the culprit to your orginal formula.

Comment: Yeah, the original formula was missing a SUM, but even with it it produces an error. Not sure what might be the problem.

Comment: OK, found the problem,  Your array formula fails if there is text.  So those blank cells you talked about, if they had say a space in them, they would cause your array to crash, but apparently the sumprodcut just kinds of ignores text.  As such, I would want to test the behaviour of sumproduct with your blanks and see if its giving you the numbers you would expect.

Comment: I've been testing a few there, and it does look like sumproduct is the better bet. :-)

Comment: Glad it was helpful, now go have that second coffee!